# React Material Modal TransitionProps not firing onEntering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tsx

So I am working to update Material UI to v5, and I first got an error that onEntering is deprecated and to use transitionprops.

I have a method, let's call it doSomething, that I want to fire when the modal opens.

If I do it like this, I don't have any errors, but doSomething is not called when the modal is opened:

```
<Modal
   TransitionProps = {{ onEntering: (): void => doSomething() }}
>
...
</Modal>
```

On the other hand, if I do the following, there is an infinite loop of doSomething being called, as well as an error about `void is not assignable to type ((node: HTMLElement, isAppearing: boolean) => void) | undefined`

```
<Modal
   TransitionProps= {{ onEntering: doSomething() }}
>
...
</Modal>
```

I have checked the material upgrade documentation, and it has no good examples of what to do on the assigning of the function/method to be called during the transitions.

It just shows that instead of `onEntering={doSomething}` to use `TransitionProps={{ onEnter, onEntering, etc. }}` which does not help in regards to how to set onEntering to call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue may stem from the fact that `TrasitionProps` exists on the [`Dialog`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog/), not the [`Modal`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/) (`Dialog` inherits from `Modal`, which in turn inherits from @mui/base's headless [`Unstyled Modal`](https://mui.com/base/react-modal/)).

### Modal

If you're attempting to handle these events on a `Modal`, you'd *pass the handlers to your own [transition component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-modal/#transitions)* (in my example, I used [`Fade`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/fade/)):

```
import Modal from "@mui/material/Modal";
import Fade from "@mui/material/Fade";

...

<Modal open={open}>
  <Fade
    onEntered={handleEntered}
    onExiting={handleExiting}
    onExited={handleExited}
    in={open}
  >
    ...
  </Fade>
</Modal>
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-field-sw9fxq?file=/demo.js

### Dialog

If you're attempting to handle these events on a `Dialog`, you'd  *pass the handlers via `TransitionProps`* to the `Dialog`:

```
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";

...

<Dialog
  open={open}
  TransitionProps={{
    onEntered: handleEntered,
    onExiting: handleExiting,
    onExited: handleExited
  }}
>
  ...
</Dialog>
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-sanne-0t5mks?file=/demo.js

Comment: Okay, so yes, this Modal element does not have anything like a Fade component on it.  I will put that in and see what happens.

Comment: So switching it from a Modal to a Dialog component, and then using the TransitionProps attribute for the Dialog appears to have sorted out the issue with no extra heavy lifting needed.   Trying to put a transition component inside the Modal component was causing more issues, but the second option worked nice and clean.   Thank you!